# Copying GnuPG keys to a new computer

Tags: encryption, linux, gnupg

I want to transfer all my GnuPG keys from a computer with Ubuntu to one with Fedora. I wonder if I can just copy all the keys in the `.gnupg` folder and then import them on the Fedora computer or if is better to use `--export` with `--output`? I have practiced this in the past, but it took so much trial and error, I am afraid I might do it the wrong way and lose data. I would appreciate a sample command for export of multiple(2) keys to files if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you also want to copy your secret keys, run both `--export` and `--export-secret-keys` and start with importing the secret keys. Also don't forget to migrate trust (`--export-ownertrust`/`--import-ownertrust`).

The easier way might be to just copy the whole GnuPG home directory including configuration, keyrings and trust to the new machine (`~/.gnupg/`), don't forget to preserve permissions. If your user ID (the numerical ID, not the name) changed, run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg` afterwards to take ownership of the files.

If you are scared about data loss: as long as you just copy the files from your old computer (and don't change them there), you can start from scratch at any time. Also -- you've got an up-to-date backup of your files anyway, haven't you?

Comment: `--export-secret-keys` and respective `--import` ask you the passwords of those keys, so I wonder, if there is any advantage in this way when comparing to just copying the secret keys or whatever there are in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` directory?